# How to set two divs inline

Tags: html, css, angular

Im trying to create a webform which allows users to input the dates which they wish to take off from work. I have two div classes that I would like to be inline horizontally and when the "Add Dates" button is pressed I want another line be available.

I tried putting the 2 div's into one larger div and setting the style to inline.

```
<div class = "Leave" style="display: inline">
                    <h4>Select Leave Code</h4>
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <!-- <mat-label>Cars</mat-label> -->
                      <select matNativeControl required>
                        <option value="personal">Personal Leave</option>
                        <option value="vacation">Vacation Leave</option>
                        <option value="sick">Sick Leave</option>
                      </select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <div class = "Dates">
                            <mat-form-field>
                                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="From" [formControl]="date">
                                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                                  </mat-form-field>
                                  
                                  <mat-form-field>
                                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="To"
                                           [formControl]="serializedDate">
                                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
                                  </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

---

button

```
 <div class = "adder">
                    <div class = "sub">
                            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add Dates+</button>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to upload a screenshot, what it looks like now is a pyramid. The Leave code drop down is on top and the two calendar icons are on the next line side by side

[How it looks on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjQd2.png)

Comment: Could you provide more information for your question, like the css classes u use. And what UI Framework do u use? I see Material, but which one? Usually I would do this by utilizing flexbox. regards

Comment: If you want things to be side by side, don't use a `div`, use a `span`. `span` is already `display: inline` by default. Or better yet, use a semantically correct element, like `fieldset` to wrap the set of fields, `label` to label each field, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you I will readup on fieldset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default layout should be fine for what you're asking.

div by default is a block element, meaning, by default, its elements will be placed in a new line.

your exact code + iterating the .dates div:

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqkr2f?file=app/sidenav-overview-example.html)
[image: image of default layout]

Comment: Thank you that worked! Quick Question, I would like there to be only one field of dates until the button is clicked. Any tips on how I would go about doing that

Comment: Please include code on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site or only in images.

Comment: @Stavm, I am trying to have each date field to have its own Leave Code associated with it. Any asuggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

`display: flex;`
This CSS property will make all child inline element.

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
</div
```

This is an example of inline child.
for more info please Check this link [CSS Flexbox Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what do you mean by "when the "Add Dates" button is pressed I want another line be available." ?

In any case, when trying to inline two objects, you should put style="display: inline" property onto very element you want to be displayed inline. Thus, try to add style="display: inline" property on  element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like the button to populate another row where a user could request more dates off if neccessary.Ex:

Leave Code v                      From    To
Leave Code v                      From    To

Comment: You should not use inline styles, use style sheets. You should not set the display characteristics of an element to be opposite of what they are by default, you should use the correct element for the job, then style as needed.